# prove that it is not uniformly convergnet. Is that solution true?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that it is not uniformly convergent $(0,\infty)$
\begin{align}
f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}
\end{align}
I know how to solve this question in another way.  I  only wonder whether the solution can be done in the following way.

We have $f_n(x) \to 0$. If it is not uniformly convergent, n depends on $(x,\epsilon)$.  If it is convergent, then $\forall  \epsilon \quad \exists N, n\geq N$  such that $|f_n(x)-0| < \epsilon$
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-0|=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2} < \frac{1}{nx} < \frac{1}{Nx} 
\end{align}
Then if we fix $\epsilon$, we can choose $\epsilon =\frac{1}{Nx} \to N=\frac{1}{\epsilon x}$.

Since N depends on $x$, it is pointwise convergent. 
Is that solution true ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pointwise convergent but WHERE???

Comment: between $(0,\infty)$

Comment: No, this is not a correct solution, I am afraid: You have shown only that *your way of proving* does not lead to the conclusion (that the sequence is uniformly convergent)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you proved that $$\forall x>0 \;  \forall \epsilon>0 \; \exists N=1/x\epsilon \; :$$

$$n>N\implies |f_n (x)-0|<\epsilon $$ this is the pointwise convergence to zero function at $(0,+\infty) $.

for uniform convergence, observe that
for $n $ great enough,
$$\sup_{x>0}|f_n (x)-0|\ge |f_n (1/n)-0|=\frac {1}{2} .$$